# Why is adding script tags in my head, messing up working code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, google-api

This following code works fine:

```
$('#transPage, #categorizePage, #IDKPage').live('pageinit', function() {
$('.theListItem .red').click(function() {
    var $changeColor = $(this).closest('div[data-theme="a"]').css("background-color", "#ff3333");
    });

$('.theListItem .green').click(function() {
    var $changeColor = $(this).closest('div[data-theme="a"]').css("background-color", "#008021");
    });

});
```

And this also works great:

```
$('#transPage, #categorizePage, #IDKPage').live('pageinit', function() {
    $('.trans .theListItem .red').click(function() {
        var $toRemove = $(this).closest('div[data-theme="a"]')

        $toRemove.animate({
            height: 0
        }, 500, function() {
            // This is the callback.
            $toRemove.remove();
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Until I uncomment this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

And then it no longer works.  Problem is that I need those scripts for other stuff to work.  Any ideas what could be wrong?  Thanks.

To further illustrate my problem the following is my entire working head which I've now posted at the bottom of the page:

```
<script src="js/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<!--script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-rc.2/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-rc.2.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0-rc.2/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-rc.2.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0-rc.2/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-rc.2.min.css"></script>-->


<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!-- <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>   
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>  -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="cubiq-iscroll-bad88fb/src/iscroll.js"></script>    




<script src="swipe/dist/jquery.swipeButton-1.2.1.js"></script>


<script src="js/scrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jQueryMobileStructure.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nikostyle.css" /> 

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: You must already have a copy of jQuery included, so you don't need to include `/1.5/jquery.min.js`, just jQueryUI.

Comment: Sounds like you are adding jquery twice.  Not only that but you are adding jquery 1.5 and jqueryui 1.8 which likely requires jquery 1.8 not 1.5.  I would guess you have some conflicts going on.  Check your javascript errors.

Comment: You don't want to put those in the head anyways.  Put them at the end of your body and make sure there aren't any duplicates that might be conflicting http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works

Comment: @m0ose89 He's using `.live()`, so there's no reason to put his code at the end of the page.

Comment: He specifically said that there is other stuff using jQuery, and I didn't see anywhere that he inferred that he was using `.live()` for all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those scripts are working already before you add the stuff into your head, I assume that means you're already referencing the jQuery scripts somewhere before or something. It would probably help if we saw more code but I assume that's what the case is.